# Apache Camel app cannot run - adress in bind

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I have single apache camel app, but when im trying to run it it says this -
http://pastebin.com/5rmD0gfm

I've 1 route which is working perfectly, and another route which is depending on my rest api which i have running on port 9000

```
public class RestApiRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("jetty:http://localhost:9000/teams")
            .process(new MyLogProcessor());
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem ? I just wanna listen to post requests on /teams endpoint and then log some information, maybe finally send an email

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you already have a process listening on port 9000 - from a previous run of the camel application that you haven't terminated successfully perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As I see stacktrace that you provided is self explaned.

You trying to run two endpoints on the same port(9000). First one is you restApi and another is route that you provided above.

In this case you can use some workarounds. On our project we use CXF for rest api. And in our case we use http://camel.apache.org/camel-transport-for-cxf.html to share same port for multiple endpoints

Comment: is there such thing for spring rest api ?

Comment: btw I don't know if I understand camel well enough. does it make any sense and is it possible to have rest api listening in the back, and when I do request to this api my api implementation gets invoked, and then camel is listening to this as well and it does its own thing ? (invoke some other api, send mail, do any service etc)

Comment: @newbie101, In current realiztion I see only one enpoint that listerns for incoming requests to `http://localhost:9000/teams`. You can simply do same things without camel like described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedded-examples.html)

Comment: @newbie101, If you rest API does not send any kind of requests to camel endpoint then I think this is impossible. Also If you rest api created using camel you can check [VM operation](http://camel.apache.org/vm.html). In this case you do not need any additional enpoint. But your application should send some requests to this endpoint